# How to load tun module in linux?

Tags: vpn, kernel-module

I cannot manage to load the `tun` module in my ArchLinux box. I’m trying
to connect with OpenVPN, but the log says:

```
nm-openvpn[6662]: Note: Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/net/tun: No such device (errno=19)

lsmod | grep tun
```

Returns nothing:

If I run:

```
sudo modprobe tun
```

It returns failure, but no error message, and lsmod still has no `tun`. The module seems to exist, as there is a `tun.ko.gz` in `/lib/modules/`.

I really dont know what else to try.

Comment: Very often this problem is caused by upgrading a kernel version without rebooting the machine. Just reboot and `modprobe tun` should work. See @Sponge5 answer for details

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This answer is probably a bit late, but I ran into the problem, exactly as described, myself.

Running OpenVPN would produce:

```
Note: Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/net/tun: No such file or directory (errno=2)
```

And running `tunctl` would produce:

```
Failed to open '/dev/net/tun' : No such file or directory
```

And this command had no output:

```
lsmod | grep tun
```

When attempting to add the `tun` module via:

```
modprobe tun
```

`modprobe` would exit with a failure error code (1), and nothing changed.

I found an alternate way of activating the tun module via `insmod`. First locate the module with this command:

```
find /lib/modules/ -iname 'tun.ko.gz'
```

Then use insmod with the returned path (I only got one match), for example:

```
insmod /lib/modules/3.6.9-1-ARCH/kernel/drivers/net/tun.ko.gz
```

For me, running that command worked, and `tunctl` and OpenVPN worked okay afterwards.

Comment: Had this too on my raspberry pi, insmod solved it (after a reboot I can modprobe as usual)

Comment: Thamks! the *insmod* command works!
Had this for an openconnect issue: Failed to open tun device: No such device

Comment: Root access needed?!

Comment: can't find /lib/modules/ -iname 'tun.ko.gz' on my Ubuntu 14.04 vps (

Comment: can't find it on CentOS 7 either.

Comment: At the time of writing this, the latest ARCH produces the following error `insmod: ERROR: could not insert module /lib/modules/4.8.2-1-ARCH/kernel/drivers/net/tun.ko.gz: Invalid module format`

Comment: You can also load it automatically if found like: `find /lib/modules/ -iname "tun.ko.gz" -exec /usr/bin/insmod {} \;`

Answer (score 27):

I ran into a similar problem when trying to run openvpn on OVH Cloud VPS, openvpn complains that cannot find TUN interface.

modprobe will always return module not found :

```
$ sudo modprobe tun
FATAL: Module tun not found.
```

Finally, I found that tun is not a module but built in kernel, so what I do to solve was created the missing dir and nod:

```
$ sudo mkdir /dev/net
$ sudo mknod /dev/net/tun c 10 200
```

And then openvpn can find and use the tun device.

To be noted that afterward, modprobe will still return an error, because tun is not a module.

```
$ sudo modprobe tun
FATAL: Module tun not found.
```

Comment: Thanks, I got this problem with OpenVPN Access Server on OVH Classic VPS after doing a dist-upgrade from Debian 7 to Debian 8. You can also do `sudo chmod 600 /dev/net/tun` like said in this article: http://wiki.vpslink.com/TUN/TAP_device_with_OpenVPN_or_Hamachi After restarting openvpn with `sudo service openvpnas restart`, I could connect with a client. But when I restart the Linux server, /dev/net/tun does not exist anymore. I don't know if it's normal but I added commands to /etc/rc.local so it will still work after reboot.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution worked for my armbi port of debian squeeze running on my android mobile. I got the same error while starting OpenVPN.

Comment: yes, `tun` is not a module.

Comment: thas works for me thanx.

Answer (score 4):

In Arch linux installing the `networkmanager-vpnc` or `NetworkManager-vpnc` package will solve the problem

Comment: this is invalid for me, I already install that package, and reinstalling does nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you do a kernelcheck before running modprobe. See note [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_module#Manual_module_handling)

An easy way is to compare the output of

```
uname -r
```

and

```
pacman -Q linux
```

If they're different, reboot. That should fix the modprobe failure.

Comment: Thank you! I'm using Manjaro and I haven't resbooted my machine since the last kernel upgrade. A simple reboot solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem where my `/lib/modules/.../modules.alias` did not contain the line

```
alias char-major-10-200 tunode_tunnel
```

So even if you've done `mknod /dev/net/tun` and have `tun.ko` somewhere in `/lib/modules/...`, it won't load unless `modules.alias` has the right incantation.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be rebooting you system and then doing `modprobe tun` as root, because the most likely cause of the failed modprobe call is a kernel version mismatch with a module version (for me that was the case).

You see, after updating the system (assuming the kernel is also updated), you continue to use the old kernel, but the modules are installed from a new kernel version. That's why you can't do modprobe right after the upgrade.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! How is this answer better than the accepted one from over 10 years ago?

Comment: Given that the reason why modprobe does not work is the mismatch between the module version and the kernel version, then such an insmod is potentially dangerous. My problem with modprobe was solved by a simple system reboot - no risky trickery required. I tried to put this note under commets to the accepted answer, but this wonderful platform says I don't have enough reputation.